# How do I match background color with PHP to match text color?

Tags: php, css, wordpress, advanced-custom-fields

I am a beginner at using PHP! I know there have been questions like this before, however, they do not work for me the way I want them too.

Here's what's going on:
I have multiple background images that I implement using css and php. Each of those images, so far, are black, white, and blue. I want to be able to write some php...again I'm a beginner so please excuse my ignorance... that changes the background image to either one of those listed above to match the color of text with it.

Some things to possibly note:
This is being done on a php file. The file also corresponds to a wordpress(ACF) plugin. I can change the text color on this wordpress plugin. I have tried using github, I have looked at previous answers on this site and google, however, I believe my lack of knowledge of php and javascript have left me more confused. I think what I am trying to achieve can be done with simple if else statements. Also it's worth noting that I want an answer in php only, not javascript or jquery or github (as these answers only confuse me more). Please help and thank you.

Here's a snip-it of the relevant code I have written so far.

```
#logo{
   position:absolute;
   top: 17px;
   left: 14px;
   height: 20px;
   padding: 7px 0 0 85px;

   background: url(<?php if $color_text = ("#FFF") 
                {echo ((<? php bloginfo("stylesheet_directory")?>)'/img/image_white.png');}?>);
   /*I wrote the above for background, I see now that you cannot
     have a php statement inside another php statement, How can I fix this?*/

   /*The below is what has been written before*/
   /*background: url(<?php bloginfo("stylesheet_directory")?>/img/image_white.png) no-repeat 0 2px;*/

  /*The below is how text color is determined in the wordpress plugin*/
  /*ignore colors_2 (it responds to a color picker) but I don't want to use it
     colors_text responds to the wordpress plugin where the user can choose white, black, or blue
   I would assume I would need to change the below php statement to work with the php statement regarding the background color change. (I would appreciate help doing this as well)*/

  color: <?php if ($colors_2 || $color_text) {echo ($color_text ? $color_text : $colors_2);}
   else echo '#005b92';?>;
   }
```

Comment: you want to change the colors based on the value set on an ACF field?

Comment: What are the field names? `colors_2` and `color_text`?

Comment: Yes, that is correct.

Comment: I assumed and tried to write out corrections to your code in my answer.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if I understand your question correctly, but if I do, the following ought to deliver what you need it to:

```
<?php

$styledir = "stylesheet_directory";
$image = "image_default.png";
$color = "color: #005b92;";

if ($color_text) {

$color = "color: ".$color_text.";";

    switch ($color_text) {
        case ("#FFF") : $image = "image_white.png"; break;
        case ("#000") : $image = "image_black.png"; break;
        case ("#00F") : $image = "image_blue.png"; break;
        default: $image = "image_default.png";
    }
}

$background = "background: url('";
$background .= bloginfo($styledir);
$background .= "/img/";
$background .= $image;
$background .= "'); ";

?>

#logo{
   position:absolute;
   top: 17px;
   left: 14px;
   height: 20px;
   padding: 7px 0 0 85px;
   <?php echo $background; ?>
   <?php echo $color; ?>
}
```

Comment: I will be back on this tomorrow, I will let you know then.

Comment: Where is the dedication Alei !

Comment: Hello Rounin, let me start off again by saying I'm a beginner so excuse my lack of knowledge. That being said, I trust your judgement and code but I have some questions. What are the periods for after the $background statements and at $color_text? Also this seems like exactly what I want to do. Logically. However, it doesn't work. Instead the code doesn't show any image for the background and messes with the placement of everything else (meaning it moves text and buttons out of place).

Comment: I just noticed that #logo is not working at all. When I check it on through "inspect element" on chrome, it's not showing up at all. Any ideas why?

Comment: "What are the periods for after the $background statements and at $color_text?" In PHP you add numbers together with a + : 1 + 7 = 8. You concatenate strings with a . : "This is a "."sentence." = "This is a sentence." The statement $sentence .= " Here is a second sentence." is a short form of $sentence = $sentence." Here is a second sentence." Both statements are identical.

Comment: "I just noticed that #logo is not working at all." There should be a terminating curly brace on the #logo style declarations. I accidentally missed typing it. I have edited the post above and added it. Check your CSS to make sure you have it too.

Comment: @Rounin, I did have the ending curly brace but still no good.

Comment: And do you also have the `?>` to demarcate the end of the `<?php` section, just before you declare the style rules for `#logo` in your CSS?

Answer (score 0):

Since you have a somewhat complex if statement, it's not recommended to write it as a [ternary operator](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.comparison.php) (`condition ? true : false`), rather it would be better to use an if statement.

In your example you are using the variable names `$colors_text` and `$colors_2`, however you haven't populated these with the ACF field values. You can do this with the [`get_field()`](http://www.advancedcustomfields.com/resources/get_field/) function to return the value, and [`the_field()`](http://www.advancedcustomfields.com/resources/the_field/) to echo the value (similar to WordPress functions in the loop: `the_title()` and `get_the_title()` for example). You can use `get_field()` in an if statement because it will return `false` if the field isn't set.

You also have some syntax errors. While it's true you can't embed PHP tags within PHP tags, your if statement for the "background" is generally incorrect. You have `if $color_text = ("#FFF")` but should have `if ($color_text == "#FFF")` - the left paren is in the wrong place and you are using `=` (assignment) instead of `==` (logical or). I think you are trying to only set the background image if the color is white (or more precisely "#FFF", since "#FFFFFF" is also the same color but wouldn't match your if). The function [`bloginfo()`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/bloginfo) will echo the results, so you don't need to `echo` in your code.

```
<?php
if ( get_field( 'colors_text' ) ){
    // not false, so use the value from color_text
    $color =  get_field( 'colors_text' );
} else 
if ( get_field( 'colors_2' ) ){
    // color_text is not set, but colors_2 is, so use that
    $color =  get_field( 'colors_2' );
} else {
    // the default if neither color_text nor colors_2 are set
    $color = '#005b92';
}
?>
<style>
#logo {
   position:absolute;
   top: 17px;
   left: 14px;
   height: 20px;
   padding: 7px 0 0 85px;

   /* if the upper case $color is either #FFF or #FFFFFF set the background image */
   <?php if ( in_array( strtoupper( $color ), array( "#FFF", #FFFFFF" ) ) ): ?>
   background: url(<?php bloginfo("stylesheet_directory")?>/img/image_white.png) no-repeat 0 2px;
   <?php endif; ?>

   /* this was set in the PHP, so we can just echo it */
   color: <?php echo #color; ?>;
}
</style>
```

Comment: Sorry, didn't realize you were the same person as above. I have already set the field names. Also now that I'm thinking, would it make a difference if the text is being read in as white instead of #FFF? Or would it not make a difference?